# The sequence whose limit of difference is zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n+1}-x_n = 0$$

First question: what is the name of such sequence and general properties?

Let $F$ be the set of all adherent values of this sequence. I need to find an example such that F is not connected. How can I think about this question?

Comment: "Let F be the set of all adherent values of this sequence. I need to find an example such that F is not connected." Actually you were probably asked to show that F **is** connected.

Comment: I was asked to show that F is connected if the sequence is bounded, that I can do. But to prove that the bounded condition is necessary, I'm asked then to find a counterexample.

Comment: If the sequence is real valued and unbounded, either there are no adherent values or the set of adherent values is connected (and since the empty set is connected, F is always connected). For sequences in R^2, say, stranger things may happen but in R...

Comment: yes in R^2, sorry I always forget the givens...

Comment: Then imagine ellipses $E_N$ with axes from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ and from $(1,N)$ to $(1,-N)$, for every $N$, and a sequence $(x_n)$ starting from $(0,0)$ then following the ellipsis $E_1$ until it is back at $(0,0)$, then following each ellipsis $E_2$ until it is back at $(0,0)$, and so on with each ellipsis $E_N$. Either by a mathematical proof or by visualization, one gets that $F$ is the union of the lines $x=0$ and $x=2$, hence disconnected.

Comment: Same idea, with an explicit formula: $$(x_n,y_n)=(\cos\log n,\sqrt{n}\sin\log n).$$ Limit set: $$x=\pm1.$$

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $x_n$ is the partial sum of the harmonic series.
$|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \frac{1}{n+1}$
and $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} |x_{n+1}-x_n| = 0$, However, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$